# that pockets of his fan base are fracturing

Tags: word-usage

Does "pockets" here mean "groups"?  I've checked out the unabridged version of Random English Dictionary and found this definition to be close - "any isolated group, area, element, etc., contrasted, as in status or condition, with a surrounding element or group:
pockets of resistance; a pocket of poverty in the central city."

I am not very sure.

> The shift raises questions about the strength of the support for Mr. Trump and suggests **that pockets of his fan base are fracturing**. Many of Mr. Trump’s fans still falsely believe he was deprived of office, but other far-right groups such as the Oath Keepers, America First and the Three Percenters have also started criticizing him in private Telegram channels, according to a review of messages.

> Source: NYTimes  [‘A Total Failure’: The Proud Boys Now Mock Trump](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/01/20/technology/proud-boys-trump.html?action=click&algo=top_conversion&block=trending_recirc&fellback=false&imp_id=967782391&impression_id=8f0c2b10-5c3a-11eb-96f4-4b0ae0ba6685&index=0&pgtype=Article&region=footer&req_id=506164720&surface=most-popular-story&variant=0_top_conversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it means.